# Persist data from docker container to host machine

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile, elastic-stack

I am running docker on windows 10 laptop, I've set up my first container running Elasticsearch using a Dockerfile and it works. Every time I stop the container and start it again the data is gone.

On my windows machine I created a folder in location `C:/Docker/esdata` and in my `elasticsearch.yml` I've added `path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data` is were data is. In the Dockerfile I added:

```
VOLUME /c/Docker/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

but this still doesn't work, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: `C:/Users` is the default shared directory in both Docker Toolbox and Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Your Dockerfile specifies the attributes of the image... the things that are the same no matter where you run the container.

```
VOLUME /c/Docker/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Is not doing what you think it is doing- you cannot force someone who runs your image later to mount that specific folder.  (VOLUME takes a single argument, the path inside the container that is to become seperate from the copy-on-write file system)  Instead, you mount the volume at run time with a docker run command...

```
docker run -v /c/Docker/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

This mounts a path on your machine to a path in the running container.  However, as pointed out above, /c/Docker is not available to the virtual machine running docker, you will have to do something more like

```
/c/Users/Docker/esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```